# how can i choose columns in a dataframe to creat a new dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("C:/Users/POP/Desktop/survay of consumers/2018/public2018.csv",header=0,encoding = 'unicode_escape'))
df1=df.iloc[:,['B2','D1E','GE2_d','ppagect4','ppeducat','ppethm','ppgender','ppinccat6','ppreg9','ppwork']]
df1
```

> > > TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.iloc`, you select columns based on their *position*. You should instead use

```
df1=df[['B2','D1E','GE2_d','ppagect4','ppeducat','ppethm','ppgender','ppinccat6','ppreg9','ppwork']]
```